# Merging 2 tables with kafka topics in KSQLDB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have 2 tables student and employee and wants to merge them into new table (student_employee) based on ID (primary key) and kafka topic in KSQLDB.

```
CREATE TABLE student_employee (
   s.id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   e.id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   e.name VARCHAR,
   e.city VARCHAR,
   e.country VARCHAR,
   FROM student s
   INNER JOIN employee e
 ) WITH (
   KAFKA_TOPIC = 'student_employee',
   VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
);
```

but I am getting error - line 2:6: Syntax Error

What should be the correct creating new table by joining SQL query and kafka topic ?

Comment: `2:6` means second line, 6 characters in at `integer`. You've mixed casing on the two id field column types. Also, you can't have two primary keys, and you're missing what to join `ON` https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/join-streams-and-tables/